# How to use tibble to calculate mean of every 15 rows of a text file in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, txt

I have a text file (with every minute data) with more than 4000 rows and 19 columns. The file structure is as follows:

```
Few lines of metadata
Date  Time AirTemp  Pres  Wind ....
2021-03-01 00:00:00 27  1017  10....
2021-03-01 00:01:00.....
```

I want to calculate mean of every 15 rows for all the columns (e.g. mean of rows 1 to 15, then mean of rows 16-30 and so on..). I want to save it in .csv file. I have used following code in R to calculate 15 rows average for all the columns.

```
df <- read.table('C:/Users/Alexia/Desktop/Test/Test1.txt', header=TRUE, 
sep = "\t", check.names = FALSE, skip=27)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 15, n()))) %>%
 summarise_all(funs(mean))
```

It ran successfully but it is giving me following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
ℹ Please use a list of either functions or lambdas:

# Simple named list: list(mean = mean, median = median)
# Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: tibble::lst(mean, median)
# Using lambdas list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated. 
2: There were 2976 warnings in `summarise()`.
The first warning was:
ℹ In argument: `Date/Time = mean(`Date/Time`)`.
ℹ In group 1: `group = 1`.
Caused by warning in `mean.default()`:
! argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 2975 remaining warnings.
```

As I am new to R, I want to understand that as the warnings mention that `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0, can I not use it in future? Does it recommend to use tibble to calculate mean? How can I use tibble or any other method to calculate every 15 rows average for all the columns and save it in a csv? Thanks.

As data is huge, I have created a sample file of 4 records. The output of dput(df) is as follows:

```
structure(list(`Date/Time` = c("2021-03-01T00:00:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:01:00", "2021-03-01T00:02:00", "2021-03-01T00:03:00"), `XY` = 
c(990641, 41, 641, 906), `R1` = c(250, 27, 57, 56), `R2` = c(85, 
84, 89, 64), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4))
```

Comment: The function `lubridate::floor_date` can round times down to the nearest 15 minutes. You could create a column called e.g.  `quarter` by doing `mutate(quarter = lubridate::floor_date(as.POSIXct(paste(date, time)), '15 minutes'))`. You could then easily use this to `group_by` and `summarise` your data into 15 minute chunks. This method has the virtue of being robust to missing rows, daylight savings changes etc.

Comment: @Allan I am getting this error : Error in paste(date, time) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' What could be the reason and How to resolve it?

Comment: In my example I forgot to capitalize `Date` and `Time` inside `paste`. Try again with capitals and it should work.

Comment: I tried that it is still giving an error: 'Error in paste(Date, Time) : object 'Time' not found.' Time column is there in df. Then why this error?

Comment: are you doing `df %>% mutate(quarter = lubridate::floor_date(as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time)), '15 minutes'))`?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I am doing the same

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question to include the output of `dput(df)` so we can help you better

Comment: @Allan - Thanks. I have added the output. I would like to mention that in the original text file, Date/Time was a single column. Using Separate function (df %>% separate(`Date/Time`, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = "T")), I have divided them into two columns Date, Time and afterwards, I am trying to calculate 15rows average.

Comment: I have used your partial dput and separated into Date and Time columns according to your code, but then I get the expected result. I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Okay, I tried again starting fresh R window. But I am still receiving the error.

Comment: We can't really help you unless you give a fully reproducible example (maybe the _full_ `dput(head(df, 20))` followed by the code that reproduces the error for anyone copy-pasting into their console). Without this, you have an error that no-one else can reproduce or help you with.

Comment: @AllanCameron Hey, I am able to resolve the error now but it is not giving me the desired results. Your code has added a new column 'quarter' in the end. As mentioned in the question, I wanted to calculate 15 rows mean and I was doing it using 'funs' in dplyr package but it is giving me warning.  I wanted to know alternate way to calculate the mean